# Casting to generic type fails in c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'd wish to save some coding by being able to create a dynamic GetControl method. My ideas is something like this

```
private T GetControl<T>(ASPxGridView control, string element)
{
    var returnedElement = (T)control.FindEditFormTemplateControl(element);
    return returnedElement;
}
```

Which I call with

```
var myElement = GetControl<ASPxTextBox>(myGridView, "UserId");
```

But, this fails miserably:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'T'

Any advices?

Comment: This is generic, not dynamic. Don't confuse the two terms. And how miserably does it fail?

Comment: The casting to the type is dynamic anyway. By the use of generics. Be constructive instead of ...

Comment: No it is not. `dynamic` has a very specific meaning in c#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: there is nothing dynamic here. Dynamic is the dynamic type introduced in .NET 4 . All your code is statically compiled. - And. Please. Provide. The. Exception!

Comment: Error code is Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'T'

Comment: Be constructive instead of... being constructive? Makes no sense.

Comment: And there you go peeps, both Darin and Konrad where constructive instead of bumptious

Comment: So comments are never constructive? Open a request on meta to abolish them then.

Comment: Comments are usually constructive, but a to large portion are simply degrading instead of constructive. Nothing personal, it's a fact.

Comment: @Trikks i think the comments are contsructive, it is important to understand that "dynamic" has a special meaning as of C#4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a generic constraint:

```
private T GetControl<T>(ASPxGridView control, string element) where T : Control
{
    var returnedElement = (T)control.FindEditFormTemplateControl(element);
    return returnedElement;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can circumvent type safety by casting via `object`:

```
var returnedElement = (T)(object)control.FindEditFormTemplateControl(element);
```

Furthermore, I would constrain your generic type to `Web.UI.Control`, if only for the purpose of self-documentation:

```
private T GetControl<T>(ASPxGridView control, string element)
    where T: System.Web.UI.Control
{
    return (T)control.FindEditFormTemplateControl(element);
}
```

Comment: With the type constraint you should not need to cast to object

Comment: @Ben I see (just tested) but I don’t understand why. This cast is completely unsafe, in fact, no more safe than without a (class) constraint.

Comment: The constraint means that T must be castable to System.Web.UI.Control, that's essentially what it does, tells the compiler to enforce that requirement.

Comment: @Ben Exactly: castable *to* `Control`. The code is casting *from* it, a whole different thing. Logically this shouldn’t behave differently from the `class` constraint, or indeed *any* constraint.

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean, sorry i was thinking back to front, but surely it works because this works GridView test = `(GridView)FindControl("SomeControlId");` i.e. you can cast from a Control to a GridView and it compiles but it might fail at runtime. Without the constraint you might be doing the equivalent of `GridView test = (string)FindControl("SomeControlId")`, which does not compile because you can't cast a Control to a string