# Cannot convert type 'System.Attribute' to generic argument 'T' - why?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, system.reflection

I'm trying to compile my desktop .NET dll to WinRT platform (Target Windows 8.1). It worked fine on desktop but in WinRT project I have that compiler error in the code:

```
internal static T[] CreateRuntime<T>(MemberInfo member, bool inherit)
{
    return member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit).Select(attr => (T)attr).ToArray();
}
```

I can't cast `Attribute` `attr`  to generic argument `T`... but why only on WinRT? Are there any differences in the language or what may cause this?

Comment: Did you put the constraint `where T : Attribute` ? The definition of `T` would be useful to see

Comment: This may also be useful: http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/net-winrt-get-custom-attributes-from-enum-value

Comment: @Rob thanks but my question is about compiler differences - not code review ;) btw when I put `T : Attribute` the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the type conversion rules in C#. From the C# 5.0 specification:

> **6.2.7 Explicit conversions involving type parameters**
>   The following explicit conversions exist for a given type parameter T:
>   •   From the effective base class C of T to T and from any base class of C to T. At run-time, if T is a value type, the conversion is executed as an unboxing conversion. Otherwise, the conversion is executed as an explicit reference conversion or identity conversion.
>   *[…there are three other bullet points, but none apply here…]*
>   The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type, which might be surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make the semantics of such conversions clear.

Unconstrained, the only known base class of `T` is `System.Object`. But in Winrt, the `GetCustomAttributes()` method [is implemented as an extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh138301(v=vs.105).aspx), returning `IEnumerable<Attribute>` instead of the `object[]` that is returned [in the .NET API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx). Thus the variable `attr` has the type `Attribute`, and not `object`.

So when you are using the .NET API, you can cast from the base class `object` to `T`, but when you are using Winrt, you cannot cast from the non-base-class `Attribute` to `T`.

You can change the known base class of `T` by adding a constraint to the method declaration:

```
internal static T[] CreateRuntime<T>(MemberInfo member, bool inherit)
    where T : Attribute
{
    return member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit).Select(attr => (T)attr).ToArray();
}
```

With the base class of `T` now being declared as `Attribute`, you can now cast from `Attribute` to `T`.

Note that this is *not* a difference in language implementation between .NET and Winrt. It's the same exact C# rules. It's simply that you are actually dealing with different implementations of `GetCustomeAttributes()`, where the return values are different, making the type of your variable `attr` different, and thus producing different results in each case.

See related questions:

[Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255178)
[C# Problem with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606101)
[Casting to generic type fails in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7269967)

I was disappointed that none of these otherwise-relevant questions and answers addressed the core of the issue, which is *why* C# makes this requirement. I've tried to do so above. However, they do all cover similar scenarios, showing how the same exact thing can happen in the context of non-Winrt code. They also illustrate the two basic solutions:

1. Use a constraint on the generic parameter (as I suggest here)
2. Cast to `object` before casting to `T`. This bypasses the generic conversion, removing context so that the compiler permits the cast. IMHO this is much less preferable; but if you cannot add the constraint for some reason (such as you're dealing with a special case that doesn't apply to all possible `T`…however undesirable such implementations are), this will work.